# JTextPane Scrolling

Tags: java, user-interface, scroll, jscrollpane, jtextpane

I am aware of the fact that there have been similar questions asked about this topic, but after a few hours of research, I have come to no solution.

My question is why no scroll bar is showing on my JTextPane.  Below is my code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JTextPane;

public class OtherNotesWindow extends JFrame{

JTextPane page;
JPanel panel;


public OtherNotesWindow() {
    super("Other Notes Window");
    init();
    page.setFocusable(true);
    this.setSize(400,400);
    this.setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLocation(400,400);
}

public void init(){
    panel = new JPanel();
    page = new JTextPane();
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(page, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scroll.setViewportView(page);
    panel.add(scroll);
    this.add(page);
}
}
```

I don't know why no scroll bar, both vertical and horizontal, aren't showing up.  Can anyone please tell me why?

Thanks in advance to anyone who replies. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a closer look at your code...

```
// Create a  panel...
panel = new JPanel();
// Create a scroll pane
page = new JTextPane();
// Create a scroll pane with page as the view
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(page, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
// A little redudent as you did this when you created the scoll pane, but what ever
scroll.setViewportView(page);
// Add the scroll pane to the panel
panel.add(scroll);
// Add the page to this...wait what??!
this.add(page);
```

This last line is you undoing, it is is removing `page` from the `JScrollPane` and simply adding to the `JFrame`...no scroll pane or anything...

You need to change it to something like...

```
this.add(panel);
```

or

```
this.add(scroll);
```

Remember, `JPanel` by default uses a `FlowLayout`, which might not meet your requirements

Answer (score 0):

`this.add(page)` should be `this.add(panel)`

Comment: because you added the ScrollPane to the panel, now you need to add the panel, and "this" references your class which extends jframe. 

so: JFRAME=>PANEL=>ScrollPane=>TextPane.

Comment: that didn't work.  It just added a tiny box to the panel and removed the JTextPane entirely.  thanks for the answer though. :)

Comment: after moving that line of code around, the Jtextpane now appears on the panel, but there is still no scrolling.  Not sure what else needs to be done.  this has never happened to me before.

Comment: You might want to expend that answer a little, I read it four or five times before it clicked...Some explanation of why the OP should do what your saying wouldn't go astray either ;)